# How do I prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^3 e^{-n^4}$ is convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^3 e^{-n^4}$

How do I know this series is convergent?
I tried to use ratio test, but it was too hard to compute due to the power($-n^4$) of $e$.

Please explain me how to prove it clearly.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked four questions during your first day on this site. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.)
For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounding test with $e^{-n}$ or even $n^3 e^{-n}$ will suffice. The exponent very obviously pushes everything to zero.

Another way is to approximate the sum with an integral (you can do it in a way that bounds the sum from above), and introduce a new variable $u=n^4$ (recognize $n^3$ as the differential part).

The ratio test isn't that bad either:

$$\frac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}e^{-((n+1)^4-n^4)}$$
This will clearly go to zero, because the exponent up there is $-(4n^3+6n^2+4n+1)<-4n-1$, so this is very strongly bounded by the exponential decay: $e^{-(4n^3+6n^2+4n+1)}<e^{-4n-1}\ll 1$.

Comment: Oh.. I though the graph of $e^-x$. but I did not know this way was correct. Thank you for your help. I understood. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint, use the integral test. To find the antiderivative, let $u=-n^4$.

Answer (score 0):

Ratio test gives

$${a_{n+1}\over a_{n}}={(n+1)^3\over n^3}e^{-4n^3-6n^2-4n-1}\to 0$$

Can you take it from here

Answer (score 0):

[The ratio test is covered here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1666983/135592)

The root test gives:

$$\sqrt[n]{n^3e^{-n^4}}=n^{\frac3n}e^{-n^3},$$

the exponential goes to zero and $n^{\frac1n}$ goes to 1 so $n^{\frac3n}\to1$, implying it's bounded.